# Navigation Bar Background Color Light with Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I add Navigation Bar in any view controller. But, I'm adding new CollectionView Controller in project. My problem is that I could not **add Navigation Bar in Collection View Controller**.
So I add Navigation Bar with code. I choose *Top Bar- "**Inferred**"* in Attributes Inspector. Here is the code.

```
//Add Navigation Bar

    let height: CGFloat = 65
    let navbar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: height))
    navbar.delegate = self
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green:49.0/255.0, blue:79.0/255.0, alpha:0.1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
```

But, the Navigation Bar Background Color in Collection View Controller is a little bit dark than other view controller. 
In other view controller, I drag and put navigation bar. 
- Navigation Bar style --> Black
- Translucent --> not enabled 
- Bar Tint Color --> #00314F 
I don't know why Navigation Bar Background Color in Collection View Controller is light than in Collection View Controller.

 Please help me how to match Navigation Bar Background Color in all view controller. 
If it is not easy to do, is there any ways to add **Navigation Bar** in CollectionViewController without embedded in Navigation Controller and without code.

Answer (score 2):

It is beacause of the Translucent property of NavigationBar. It gives an effect where the image color looks faded as if a layer has been put on the bar, hence the color looks a little and different. Set off the translucent property of navigation bar as shown below. You can write this code in any lifecycle methods.

> self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

Answer (score 0):

It is because of translucent i think. When the navigation bar is not translucent, view can't locate behind the navigation bar to show what it has. But when is translucent, view stays behind the navigation bar and with view's color, you see it darker.

Comment: Hi @AtaerCaner, do you have any idea to solve this problem bro?